# Querydsl delete query using limit

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, mariadb, querydsl

I have a one question.

I want to use limit for delete query with querydsl. Is there any way?

```
delete(wedul).where(wedul.id.eq(10)).limit(10)
```

Comment: your database don't allow delete query using limit.
check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111961/mysql-limit-on-delete-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA (on which hibernate and querydsl is built) does not support something like a limit or rownum for deletes, because it is not a universally supported database concept.

A common approach to solving this would be to delete from the table where the 'id' in contained within a subquery, and the place the limits on the subquery.

See this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828624/limit-delete-query-with-hibernate)